# How does Unity.MVC5 instantiate Controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I cannot find where and how Unity.MVC5 (Nuget package) sits inside core MVC entities to instantiate controllers. It is working well for me and can instantiate my controller that does not have a parameterless constructor, along with the injected classes, but I do not understand how it works.

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Unity register its own `ControllerFactory : ` [IControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd470353(v=vs.98))  with `CreateController` method. This method is called by ASP.NET with passing to it request's context and Unity, depending on that information, creates corresponding controller with all needed dependenсies

Comment: that was useful, helped me google for the right keyword and here you go: https://dzone.com/articles/custom-controller-factory
however, in MVC5 I do not see where the default controller factory is set to be the custom one. Maybe it is done in unity libraries? and somehow hooked up to some events in Global.ascx to fire off at when application_start is called?